# CREATE a VPN Connection on Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, vpn

I need to be able to *CREATE* a new VPN connection through the command line. I have seen things like `rasdial` but they are all for connecting to an existing VPN, not creating one, then joining it. The only way I know, is in the `Create a VPN connection` GUI. If anyone knows a way to do this out of the Windows CMD, or to make a batch file that creates, then connects to the VPN, that would be tremendously helpful. If it works in Windows 7, and Windows 10, that would be preferred, and I'm also okay with having a portable executable to complete the task if necessary. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614465/establish-a-vpn-connection-in-cmd

Comment: [Establish a VPN connection in cmd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21844165)

Answer (score 3):

Add-VpnConnection -Name $VPNConnectionName -ServerAddress $VPNServer -TunnelType Pptp -SplitTunneling -DnsSuffix $DNSSuffix -AllUserConnection -Force

Answer (score 2):

Powershell can be used for this purpose.
Microsoft has a complete guide about this called:
[Deploying VPN Connections by Using PowerShell and Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431700(v=ws.10).aspx)

Note: Add-VpnConnection command is directly supported since windows 8.1, you may use this directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Connection Manager Administration Kit. Then all you have to do is put it on the computer's hard drive and then you can use RASDial to connect to the vpn using the file CMAK will spit out. And if you have remote access to the computer just create a task in task scheduler to run at startup and then re-run if the connection is lost.

Sources:

CMAK Help Link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739464(v=ws.11).aspx

RASDial Help Link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff859533(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create using the following bat running as an administrator:

@echo off 
cls 
echo.

echo Wait a moment while the VPN is being configured...

PowerShell.exe -Command "Add-VpnConnection -Name LAB_RB -ServerAddress 191.1.1.1 -AllUserConnection -AuthenticationMethod Chap -EncryptionLevel Optional -Force -L2tpPsk PassWord@2021 -PassThru -RememberCredential -SplitTunneling -TunnelType L2tp" > config.log"

route add -p 172.16.5.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.198.254 > null

echo. 
pause

If you have already solved it is registered here for people like that until yesterday I was looking for this feature and through this topic I managed to solve my need.

Comment: It's not very useful if you don't explain what changes needed for others to use it. Obviously this is very specific for your vpn, such as ips, username/pass